# set cookies on an another page through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

I have 3 files ... the signup.js

```
$("#signup-form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var theForm = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
    url: "php-includes/signup-parser.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: theForm,
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){
            // Redirecting
            location.href = "account.php";
        }
    }
})
```

the signup-parser.php

```
        # Cookie creator
        setcookie('id',1,60);

        # Manually set it,if not set
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['id']))
            $_COOKIE['id'] = 1;
```

and finally the main page account.php

```
    # is_a_cookie_set is function that checks if a cookie is set.
    if (!is_a_cookie_set()){
        die("<h1>No cookie set</h1>");
    }
```

My aim here is to set a cookie on the signup-parser and then redirect to the account page,which requires a cookie to be set. The problem is that no cookie can be set in the signup-parser...i keep getting no cookie set...any ideas where this is wrong?

Comment: Actually you're likely setting up the cookie, but it isn't available to you at the main page until a reload occurs. AJAX does not make the cookie ubiquitous. Same thing with sessions.

Comment: How do i make a reload happen on the other page then?

Comment: By not using AJAX with your sign up form and adding a redirect back to account.php It isn't the other page that needs to reload, it is account.php that needs the action.

Comment: In account.php: `if (!isset($_COOKIE["id"])){
        die("<h1>No cookie set</h1>");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong third param. You must set it like this, cookie will be available in next 60 minutes. Also you need fourth param, to enable cookie available within entire domain.

```
 setcookie('id', 1, time() + 60, '/');
```

Comment: Can you show your is_a_cookie_set() function ? For me it works.                                       if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])) {
 echo "set";
}

Comment: `function is_a_cookie_set(){
        if (count($_COOKIE) > 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: You need one more param, path and then cookie will be available within entire domain. Take a look on my modified example and try please.

Comment: Path is optional. So is expiration time. Only 2 things are needed - the cookie name and the cookie value. The real problem here is using AJAX.

Comment: You have files in one folder and files in this folder: php-includes. You must include then path param to make cookie available, give it a try.

Comment: If a domain is not set the cookie defaults to the host portion even if using a subdomain (if on subdomain.mydomain.com, by default it’s set to mydomain.com). Domain cookies are included in subdomains. Your assertion is incorrect @BranislavM.

Comment: I simulated full example on my computer and it works with 4 params and without fourth param didn't work. If you don't want to try it's ok, but it works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

There is literally no point in using that function.  You can just use `empty()`, it checks both if it is set and if it contains a value. Right now you are just checking for any sort of cookie. Focus on finding out if your `$_COOKIE['id']` contains any value, don't try to get fancy with a function like that.

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['id']){
  die("No cookie");
}
```

setcookie needs two parameters, the rest are optional.  Your third parameter is incorrect, you need to use `time() + (int)` the int is in seconds and works with a Unix timestamp.

With an AJAX request success is returned no matter what the script returns, so returning false on an AJAX request is still considered a success.  Only when the script execution fails (500 errors) does it return error.  So you're redirected regardless of whether or not the cookie is set.

Also try not using an integer value, put quotes around it, or store it in a variable.

```
setcookie('id', '1') ;
```

or

```
$num = 1;
$time = (24 * 60 * 60); // one day
setcookie('id', $num, $time);
```

I suggest checking out some docs on setting cookies if you're still having trouble: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp